# UILabel not animating

Tags: animation, uiview, uilabel

i want a label to animate when the application launches, but it's not working

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self  LaunchApp];
}

-(void)LaunchApp
{

    CGRect frame = _mylabel.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 100; 

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^ {

                         [_mylabel setFrame:frame];

                     }
                     completion:^ (BOOL finished) {                     
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the view with xib's or interfaceBuilder?

If so, try selecting the xib and deselecting use autoLayout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` called once the view controller's view is loaded but it is not displayed at the screen at this point.
You probably want to subscribe to one of `UIApplication`'s notifications. Please read the documentations about app's state transitions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html to get what you really need.